# Python spark streaming output

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to execute this program but don't see any output on the console where does the pprint statements are written.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: hdfs_wordcount.py <directory>", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingHDFSWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
    lines = ssc.textFileStream(sys.argv[1])
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
                  .map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
                  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/streaming/hdfs_wordcount.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this program will read content from files in directory that generated after program execution

I have one post related to this type of spark program.
you can also check video in this post
 http://www.neerajbyte.com/post/spark-streaming-from-text-files-using-pyspark-api/

https://youtu.be/bm28UYrYOeE